# Github Open Pull Requests

Tags: git, github, commit, pull-request

I'd like to ask a question regarding Github, specifically pull requests.

Let's say for example that there is an **open** pull request.

I made a commit 'feat: add feature', and then a little while later someone else made a couple more commits to the pull request, 'feat: add feature b' and 'feat: add feature c', if I wanted to  rename **my** original commit, is there a way to do that?

If I simply did something like `git reset HEAD~`, would that ruin the two commits made after mine?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to change a commit other than the most recent one, you probably need an _interactive rebase_. That means a force push, though, as all subsequent commits will also be rewritten; if other people are working on the same branch you'll need to coordinate carefully with them.

Comment: Note this is nothing to do with GitHub and PRs, really, just editing commits on a branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your renaming of the first commit by `interactive rebasing`.

if there are 3 commits on the head use this command
`git rebase -i HEAD~3`

This will open up something like this

```
pick a1beca Your commit
pick a2beca feat: add feature b
pick a3beca feat: add feature c

...
```

Hit "i" on the keyboard to activate interactive mode. Go with reword for your commit

```
reword a1beca Your commit
pick a2beca feat: add feature b
pick a3beca feat: add feature c

...
```

Hit "esc" to exit interactive mode. And then `:wq` This will then ask you to type your desired commit message.

For more information read [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History). Some practice will take you there.

Answer (score -1):

You can change your commit by run this code:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

If you want to undo both commit and changes: ⚠️ Be sure that you want to lose the changes:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Comment: That doesn't change the message of the the OP's commit, that drops the most recent commit.